# Does the suffix "-ria" in Spanish always mean "a place that sells?"

Tags: gramática, sufijos

I noticed in Spanish the suffix -ria seems to mean "a place that sells" 
For instance:

- A laundromat is *lavandería*
- A meat store is a *carnicería*
- A fruit stand is a *frutería*
- A bread store is a *panaderia*
- A coffee shop is a *cafetería*
- A book store is *librería*

Yet that doesn't always hold up, because a brothel/ house of prostitution would be translated as "sexoria" - why doesn't it?

Comment: But notice that [prostibularia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UQsP983) does exist.

Comment: In such case it would be replaced by **prostíbulo** directly. I have never heard the form prostibuleria.

Comment: "Sangria" is not a blood bank.

Comment: You won't buy idiots in a *tontería*, ill people in an *enfermería*, kids in an *infantería*, pirates in a *piratería* or pork in a *porquería*…

Comment: @jlliagre In living in America, those things you listed aren't signs on stores. But I was using my examples to make a general rule, to see if it carried across.

Comment: Yes, my comment was merely a joke. You should edit the title of your question if you want to avoid such comment or answers though.

Comment: @jlliagre couldn't a tontería be a joke shop if a store was labeled such? (Foolishness/ idiocy is the translation I got from google)

Comment: *Tontería* comes from *tonto* (fool/idiot). I'm not a native Spanish speaker but perhaps you might try to coin *tonterería* or *tonteriría*…

Comment: Is it -ría or -ería?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All these nouns come from the place where a person realizes a specific job.

- Lavandería → lavand*ero*
- Carnicería → carnic*ero*
- Frutería → frut*ero*
- Panadería → panad*ero*
- Cafetería → cafet*ero*
- Libería → libr*ero*

As you see, all of them share the *-ero* suffix, which is quite common in professions whose name comes from Latin. And this one is described by DRAE:

> [**-ero, ra**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=G2rZOMn)
>
> *Del lat. -arius.*
>
> 1. suf. En sustantivos, indica oficio, ocupación, profesión o cargo. Ingeniero, jornalero, librero.
> 2. suf. Forma derivados que designan utensilios o muebles. Billetero, perchero, llavero.
> 3. suf. Significa lugar donde abunda o se deposita algo. Hormiguero, basurero.
> 4. suf. Se refiere a árboles frutales. Albaricoquero, melocotonero, membrillero.
> 5. suf. En adjetivos significa, en general, carácter o condición moral. Altanero, embustero, traicionero.

In this case, all your examples would fall in the first case: *substantives indicating trade, profession, occupation or position*.

However, *-ria* is also present in words like [*lujuria*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NgoG0zM) (lust, carnal desire) and many others. Among them, those having the suffix [*-uria*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=b9UOcK7) that relate to urine issues.

So: yes, it can be the case in multiple cases, but we cannot say that suffix -*ria* is only related to places that sell things.

> Yet that doesn't always hold up, because a brothel/ house of prostitution would be translated as "sexoria" - why doesn't it?

As you know, languages are not built all in one shot. So as much as many professions get their name from Latin, as we just saw, many others come from other origins. And this also for the places where they develop their profession. In the case of your question, brothel can be *burdel*, [*lupanar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Nidcjwm), *mancebía*, [*prostíbulo*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UQsTcwb)... many with Latin origin, but others with Catalan or Occitan one (burdel).

And the same applies with suffixes: it is not a [bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) between a certain suffix and a meaning, but other words can have it without sharing the meaning.

Comment: Please notice that the suffix -ría is not the same as -ria (if it's actually a suffix), because of the different accent and pronunciation.

Comment: The suffix meaning "place of work" is [-ía](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KrUUlKb).

Answer (score 5):

According to [Corominas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diccionario_cr%C3%ADtico_etimol%C3%B3gico_castellano_e_hisp%C3%A1nico), most of the words you cite (if not all) are attested around the XIII-XIV centuries, *after* the corresponding *-ero(a)* word (lavandera, carnicero), X-ero meaning *the one who sells X*, and sometimes a regular derivation from an existing Latin word for the profession. This suggests that X-ería is nothing but the place where X-eros work (as @Laiv notes).

Probably there is no *sexería* for two reasons: on one hand, the one who *sells* sex has its own words (not *sexero*); on the other hand, such concepts are usually treated differently since they tend to be considered rude. (There is, however, a word *[putería](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UjfG9eb)*, rude and informal, with one meaning for the place where *putas* work).

Finally, *X-ería* does not *always* mean a place to sell X. Some counterexamples:

- *[Pedantería](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SIDehHa)* (pedantry)
- [*Chulería*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=92yBszk) (arrogance or grace)

Answer (score 4):

Is not "-ria" the *morfema* you are trying to understand. It's "[-ia](https://es.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%C3%ADa#/languages)".

> **2.**
>
> Forma sustantivos femeninos con el >significado de "taller o almacén",
> a partir de palabras con el
> sufijo -ero.Ejemplo:«sombrerero → sombrerería»
>
> taller o almacén con -ía, derivados de palabras con -ero, -era

-ia is a morfema that modifies the meaning of a noun providing the noun the property of "warehouse or workshop". But not property of "store".

Sex can not be stored :-) and sex can not be  built/created/produced by any workshop.

The morfema is valid for nouns that means professions:

- Fruta -> Frut**ero** -> Fruter**ía**

Happens with sex that there's not a sex crafter/productor/creator.

- Sex -> Sexero -> Sexeria

Neither Sexero nor Sexeria exists (I think), so the rule to transform the monema (meaning) of -ero/-era into -ia is not possible.